# Find the orthogonal to a clothoid spiral from an offset coordinate

Tags: curves

At the moment, I'm implementing an algorithm which defines a spiral using the method outlined in the following paper:

https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-59-199/S0025-5718-1992-1134736-8/S0025-5718-1992-1134736-8.pdf

One of the challenges I've yet to sort out is how to calculate a point on the spiral given a point that is offset from it.  Essentially, it's calculating the orthogonal vector from a point near the spiral and the corresponding distance.  This appears to require an iterative process to zero in on the location with a desired level of precision, as suggested here:

[Distance between point and a spiral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175106/distance-between-point-and-a-spiral?newreg=e0c8d30483cd49588f92bbb9adae6639)

I haven't taken the time to sort out how to adapt that for my case just yet, as I was hoping I could get some direction on whether or not this is the sort of approach I need to implement - or is there something more efficient / direct?

Comment: A problem and a question. The problem : the first pointer doesn't point on an AMS document but to the same MathStackExchange Question/Answer(s). The question : which kind of spiral are you mentionning ? There are so many of them... you mentionned a clothoid, whereas the MathSE document mentions a Fermat spiral. A remark : archimedean spirals are ideally fit for offset issues...

Comment: The link is fixed in the first case.  
In the second, I referenced the post if only because it was one of the few references I could find relevant to what I want to do - despite the type of spiral.  I suspect the approach would be similar in my case, although I'm not working in polar coordinates.  I also imagined an approach similar to this - basically an iterative, binary search method.  I'm curious to know if there's a more direct way of finding that coordinate, even if it isn't a clothoid.  It may give me a clue as to where to go looking... or what question to ask next. :)

Comment: I should also note that the reason I'm focused on clothoids is because this is a project related to transportation engineering, which specifically uses clothoid spirals for the fact that they maintain a constant curvature.

Comment: binary/adaptive step/ search on $s$ (distance along the clothoid) getting its corresponding $(x,y),\theta$ , while calculating the angle from the $(x,y)$ point on the clothoid to your given point, until this angle is $\theta+\pi/2$.